# how to bind textbox value to span

Tags: jquery

How can I bind `input textBox` value to `span`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Btn3').click(function () {
    var txtvalue=$('#txtx1');
    console.log(txtvalue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtx1" /><br />
<span id="txtSpan"></span>
<input type="button" value="Appended-textBox" id="Btn3" />
```

When I click on Button textbox value should appear in span And console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Btn3').click(function() {
    var txtvalue = $('#txtx1').val();
    $("#txtSpan").text(txtvalue);
    console.log(txtvalue);
  });
});
```

```html
 <!-- Include this line of code --><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtx1" /><br />
<span id="txtSpan"></span>
<input type="button" value="Appended-textBox" id="Btn3" />
```

Base on your **jQuery** code above, you are lacking `})` for the `document.ready()` and to get the value of the input box use `.val()` then to display it use `.text(variable inside here)`.

Comment: Error as "#txtx1".val is not a function

Comment: include jquery.. copy the `<script>` above

Comment: @MDmohi just mark this as the answer later for +rep for both of us and so this question will be remove from the unanswered..^^

Answer (score 0):

let try this

Step 1: make sure you have given reference for jQuery source file

Step 2:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#Btn3').click(function () {
      var txtvalue=$('#txtx1').val();
      $('#txtSpan').html(txtvalue);
      console.log(txtvalue);
   });
});
```